# How come my code displays the wrong image?

Tags: javascript, mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfquery

I'm trying to teach myself cold fusion, javascript, and mysql.  I created a page where user can click on an image and then a pop up window will show the full image.  My code compiles, but it always displays the first image from my image database.  I spent a lot of time on this but couldn't figure out what I'm missing.  Can someone give me a hint on how to fix this?  Thanks in advance for your help!

File 1: full_article_view.cfm

```
<!--- retrieve the full article as well as its images --->
<CFQUERY NAME="myQuery1" Datasource="mydb" >
SELECT articles.article_ID, articles.article_title, articles.article_author,
        articles.article_date, articles.article_content, article_image_mapping.aim_articleID
FROM articles
INNER JOIN article_image_mapping ON articles.article_ID = article_image_mapping.aim_articleID
WHERE articles.article_ID = #URL.ID#
GROUP BY article_image_mapping.aim_articleID
</CFQUERY>

<CFQUERY NAME="myQuery2" Datasource="mydb" >
SELECT images.image_ID, images.image_thumbpath, images.image_fullpath, article_image_mapping.aim_articleID, article_image_mapping.aim_imageID
FROM images
INNER JOIN article_image_mapping ON images.image_ID = article_image_mapping.aim_imageID
WHERE article_image_mapping.aim_articleID = #URL.ID#
</CFQUERY>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script Language="JavaScript">
        function popup()
        {
            settings="toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,"+
            "status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,"+
            "resizable=yes";

            MyNewWindow = window.open("full_img.cfm?toshow=images.image_ID");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <!--- Page Title --->
    <h3>Full Article View</h3>

    <!--- Page Content --->
    <div align="left">
        <!--- Display article title, author, date, and full content --->
        <cfoutput query="myQuery1">
            <b>#ucase(myquery1.article_title)#</b>
            <hr>
            <p style="color:##848181; font-size:12px">#myquery1.article_author# :: #myquery1.article_date#</p>
            #myquery1.article_content#<br/>
        </cfoutput>
        <br>
        <!--- Display images associated with article--->
        <cfoutput query= "myQuery2">
            <a href="" onClick="popup();">
            <img src="#myquery2.image_thumbpath#" alt="image thumbnail">
            </a>
        </cfoutput>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2: full_img.cfm

```
<CFQUERY NAME="myQuery3" Datasource="mydb" >
SELECT image_ID, image_thumbpath, image_fullpath
FROM images
WHERE image_ID = #URL.toshow#
</CFQUERY>

<cfoutput>
<img src="#myquery3.image_fullpath#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I'm not a cf expert but, shouldn't you display the `cfoutput` as a loop iteration or a resultset? http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_lists.cfm http://www.quackit.com/coldfusion/tutorial/coldfusion_query_of_queries.cfm

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  The cfdump tag makes this easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your popup() function you are referncing images.image_ID.   This will come over as "images.image_ID", and not translate to the id.

You could change your popup to pass in the ID that you want.

```
 <script Language="JavaScript">
    function popup(id)
    {
        settings="toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,"+
        "status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,"+
        "resizable=yes";

        MyNewWindow = window.open("full_img.cfm?toshow=" + id);
    }
</script>
```

Then in your HTML/CFML code

```
<!--- Display images associated with article--->
    <cfoutput query= "myQuery2">
        <a href="" onClick="popup(#myQuery2.image_ID#);">
        <img src="#myquery2.image_thumbpath#" alt="image thumbnail">
        </a>
    </cfoutput>
```

I know you are teaching yourself ColdFusion. I'd recommend you use the [cfqueryparam](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=queryDB_5.html) tag in your queries to protect against SQL attacks. You would need to use it around your #URL.ID# in your queries.

So this:

```
...WHERE articles.article_ID = #URL.ID#
```

would be this:

```
...WHERE articles.article_ID = <cfqueryparam value = "#URL.ID#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">
```

Hope that helps some.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOO MUCH FOR YOUR HELP!!! After I made the changes in my program, everything works great!!  By any chance, do you mind to give me a couple online resources on where I can learn cold fusion? =)

Answer (score 0):

According to the link I've commented, you should specify the query in the cfoutput `query` attribute

```
<cfoutput query="myQuery3">
<img src="#image_fullpath#">
</cfoutput>
```